# Best practice for handling missing properties in a JavaScript object?

Tags: javascript, json

I have a client that makes rest web service call and from calling the service returned data is JSON object. It has following field names as name and age. I ran into a case where fields are empty in returned data. Received this `{}` instead of `{"name":"john doe","age":"23"}`. What would be the best way to handle exception like that in JavaScript?

Comment: What does the call to the service look like? It's possible you're querying on an ID or search criteria that return no matching records. Please show us your code.

Comment: Is this call made via ajax or are you serializing this object on the server side?  Is this going to return a single object or an array of objects?

Comment: To handle this in *javascript* enough to check `if (data.name) {  };` however, I'm not sure this is a real question.

Comment: Thank you all for your reply back. I pass unique ID and web service uses that ID querying a matching data. I expected if data is not found returned Single json object would have {"name": "", "age":""}, but just came in as "{}". For now I will go with if(data.name) { }; Thanks Tommi for your suggestion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends on the data you're expecting.

The classic way would be

```
if (typeof object.property === "undefined") {
    ...
}
```

which also implies that `undefined` is not an acceptable value (and it shouldn't). But if it's not good for you, there's always

```
if (!object.hasOwnProperty("property")) {
    ...
}
```

If you expect a *non-empty* string (or a non-zero number), you can shortcut to:

```
if (!object.property) {
    ...
}
```

But if you need to accept empty strings or zeroes, this is very common too:

```
if (object.property == null) {
    ...
}
```

This rejects values like `undefined` (which should be your case) *and* `null` (which may be another unacceptable value).

But, in the end, instead of an empty object I'd recommend to return `null` and do like this:

```
if (object != null) {
    // do your stuff with name and age
    ...
}
```

Comment: "_It depends on the data you're expecting_" ...He receives `{}` :)

Comment: @davidkonrad Indeed, but I took that as just an example (as clearsky said "exceptions like that"), so I gave a broader answer.